# Identity theorem for general Schauder basis

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

The (real-analysis) identity theorem broadly states the following: Given $U \subset \mathbb{R}$ open and an analytic function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, we can uniquely continue $f$ to the whole $\mathbb{R}$.

The proof of the theorem basically comes down to the fact that analytic functions have everywhere converging Taylor expansions. What puzzles me is the explicit usage of a polynomial basis. What happens if we use another basis?

---

Let's assume we have an interval $I=[a,b]$ and a Banach-space of functions $\mathcal{B}(I)$ which has a Schauderbasis $\{\psi_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$. Let's assume there is an open interval $I' \subset I$ and on the interval, we can express a function $f \in \mathcal{B}(I) $ by
$$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i \psi_i(x)$$
Is there an equivalent identity theorem? I.e. can we continue this function to the whole interval $I=[a,b]$? If not, why does this property fail?

Answer (score 1):

The property fails already in two dimensional space of functions.
Let $f=\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}$ and $g=\mathbf{1}_{(1,2]}.$ For $I'=[0,1]$ and $I=[0,2]$ we have $$f(x)+g(x)=f(x)\quad x\in I'$$ but $$f(x)+g(x)\neq f(x)\quad x\in I$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know that the property is in general false. My question is more like: what is the largest function class which has an identity theorem. And why one uses polynomials as basis functions in the formulation of the identity theoren but not other basis functions

Comment: Very often the trigonometric functions $\sin(nx)$ and $\cos(nx)$ are used.

Comment: But is there an identity Theorem for a Fourier basis?